# How can i inherit from two tables of a TPT hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Consedering the classes below

```
public class Customer { }
public class LegalCustomer : Customer { }
public class NaturalCustomer : Customer { }
```

and that I'm using the TPT inheritance ([Entity-Framework Tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx))

How can I write/model a class that can be a LegalCustomer or NaturalCustomer?

I tried referencing the both tables with nullable relationships, but I don't know if this are the best way to do that.

Comment: Skimming, you want TPH not TPT.  Discriminator will be a hint to Ef what type to deserialize in to.

Comment: :/ Can't I do it with TPT ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the terms. TPT is table per type (or concrete type). In your scenario this would mean that inherited properties would be mapped to both the LegalCustomer and NaturalCustomer tables. There would be no Customer table. If it's TPH, then as @brumScouse said, the customer table would contain a discriminator.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But still I don't known how can I write a class that can be the both: LegalCustomer and NaturalCustomer